# Run-time Component at cursor position

Tags: delphi, runtime, components, delphi-7

I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the web. Tried Google and many others.

In Delphi 7 how to create a run-time component at cursor position?

I tried a simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.TButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var NewCheckBox: TCheckBox;
MB: TMouseButton;
CPos: TPoint;
begin
  GetCursorPos(CPos);
  NewCheckBox:=TCheckBox.Create(Self);
  NewCheckBox.Parent:=Form1;
  NewCheckBox.Caption:='NewCheckBox';
  NewCheckBox.Left:=CPos.X;
  NewCheckBox.Top:=CPos.Y;
end;
```

But this doesn't work right. The components appear not at the cursor and I cannot place them wherever I want. The code places the component just as I click the button not when I click on the form where I want it to be placed. I want to create a visual of the component that is about to be created and drag it all the way to the form from the button on a toolbar.

I tried Drag-And-Drop but nothing works then, the Drop procedure always shows me a deny sign and does nothing.

Comment: we need more context here, what do you mean with "it doesn't work right"? maybe a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: `GetCursorPos()` reports **screen coordinates**. The `Left`/`Top` properties use **client coordinates** that are relative to the `Parent`. Use the Parent's `ScreenToClient()` method to translate, eg: `CPos := Form1.ScreenToClient(CPos);`

Comment: This won't end well. All your controls will begin life on top of that button .........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will create your checkbox when you right-click on the form.  It could do with a bit of refinement, e.g. to handle adding multiple checkboxes, etc, but might help you get going in the right direction.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateCheckBox(X, Y : Integer);
begin
  // NewCheckBox is a Form variable
  NewCheckBox:=TCheckBox.Create(Self);
  NewCheckBox.Parent:=Form1;
  NewCheckBox.Caption:='NewCheckBox';
  NewCheckBox.Left:= X;
  NewCheckBox.Top:= Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift:
    TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   if Button = mbRight then
     if NewCheckbox = Nil then
       CreateCheckBox(X, Y);
end;
```

Btw, when you use drag & drop on your form, getting the entry sign means that you have not set up an `OnDragOver` event for the form which sets the `Accept` parameter to True.

Comment: This changes things.. But what if I have a toolbar where I keep an image of every component and when i click there I wanna drag a newly created component onto a page of a pagecontrol.

Comment: " But what if ..."  Implementing that would be rather more complicated but not very difficult once you get to grips with Delphi's drag&drop facilities.  In fact the most difficult bit would probably be creating a custom drag image for each component on your toolbar  Find out about those things, try your own implementation, then post a new q if you get stuck.

Comment: Okay. Yet, i'm  guessing i'm heading the wrong way.

Comment: Well, it is good to know these things, but how far to take them depends on what your objective is.  If you want to implement run-time form design, there are existing libraries which already do that without you having to re-invent a rather large wheel.  The freeware JEDI library contains at least one rt/time form designer, for instance, iirc.

Comment: I posted a question about what I wish to get in result.